# angularjs: custom directive to check if a username exists

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-ngmodel

I have my registration form with textbox username. I want to do is when the user enter the username, the custom directive will check if the entered username is exists in the database.

directives.js

```
angular.module('installApp').directive('pwCheck', function ($http) {
  return {
    require: 'ngModel',
      link: function (scope, elem, attrs, ctrl) {
        elem.on('blur', function (evt) {
          scope.$apply(function () {
          $http({ 
          method: 'GET', 
          url: '../api/v1/users', 
          data: { 
            username:elem.val(), 
            dbField:attrs.ngUnique 
          } 
      }).success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        ctrl.$setValidity('unique', data.status);
        });
       });
      });
     }
    }
});
```

If it's exists, my `div class = "invalid"` will shown in the html form with label "Username already exists."

registration.html

```
    <form name  = "signupform">
      <label>{{label.username}}</label>
        <input type="text" id = "username" name = "username" ng-model="user.username" class="form-control"></input>
        <div class="invalid" ng-show="signupform.username.$dirty && signupform.username.$invalid"><span ng-show="signupform.username.$error.unique">Username already exists.</span>
        </div>
    </form>
```

But right now, they are not working :-(,am I doing right? Please advice or suggest me things I should do. Thanks in advance.

Comment: where did u use `pw-check` directive in your html ?

Comment: I used it to compare  two password in textbox.

Comment: so how do u call the directive in your html ?

Comment: put a `console.log()` inside the `link` function and check wthere its working or not

Comment: Hello @K.Toress what variable will I put to console log? Sorry this is the first time I work in directives. I tried this `console.log(elem.val() == user.username);` , but nothing is display in console. Thanks

Comment: @K.Toress am I doing the right way?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

there is a great [tutorial](http://www.yearofmoo.com/2014/09/taming-forms-in-angularjs-1-3.html#asnychronous-validation-via-asyncvalidators) by **yearofmoo** about $asyncvalidators in angular1.3. it allows you to easily show pending status when the field is being checked by the backend:

here's a working **[plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/Qjz7OUJRYiG8TXoTL3JE?p=preview)**

```
app.directive('usernameAvailable', function($timeout, $q) {
  return {
    restrict: 'AE',
    require: 'ngModel',
    link: function(scope, elm, attr, model) { 
      model.$asyncValidators.usernameExists = function() {

        //here you should access the backend, to check if username exists
        //and return a promise
        //here we're using $q and $timeout to mimic a backend call 
        //that will resolve after 1 sec

        var defer = $q.defer();
        $timeout(function(){
          model.$setValidity('usernameExists', false); 
          defer.resolve;
        }, 1000);
        return defer.promise;
      };
    }
  } 
});
```

html:

```
<form name="myForm">
  <input type="text" 
        name="username"
        ng-model="username" 
        username-available 
        required
        ng-model-options="{ updateOn: 'blur' }">
  <div ng-if="myForm.$pending.usernameExists">checking....</div>
  <div ng-if="myForm.$error.usernameExists">username exists already</div>
</form>
```

note the use of [ng-model-options](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngModelOptions), another cool feature of 1.3

---

**edit**

here's a [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/b5FhEYE8c1xw5as89BjJ?p=preview) that shows how to use $http in the directive. note that it is only requesting another .json file, that contains a true/false value. and the directive will set validity on the ng-model accordingly.

Comment: That is great @Nitsan Baleli. I am new to directives may I ask you another question, can you help me how to access my backend? I tried the plunker and no matter what I enter it always said that the user is already exists. I know I need to add some code but I do not know how to access my backend via directives and compare them. Thanks a lot in advance

Comment: hi there. I saw the updated answer and fork it :-). I put some values inside the backend.json. I entered them one by one and it's okay its display "user already exists" but when I enter a value which is not listed in the .json it still displays "user already exists", am I missing something? Thank you again, Here is the link http://plnkr.co/edit/2kIjx46buEinjpWx9rpR?p=preview

Comment: @Yaoming keep in mind that setting the model as valid/invalid is made with this command: model.$setValidity('usernameExists', res.data); so what ever the backend gives you, you need to decide and set the appropriate true/false value on the model.

Comment: Hello is this correct `   return $http.get('../api/v1/users').then(function(res)`?

Comment: Okay let's chat. . Where do you want?

Comment: Sorry if I am too much. . But I need your help, what should I do to access my backend?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/71765/discussion-between-nitsan-baleli-and-yao-ming).

Comment: Thank you Nitsan Baleli. Your code now is working in my project, I just changed some process but it works fine. Thank you a lot. :-)

Comment: Hi @NitsanBaleli I've tried your method, but it seems the ngModel value didn't get updated, did I missed something ?

Comment: @user3860691 try this approach http://plnkr.co/edit/QrI9Y9W72ejCKZXq1I3v?p=preview

Comment: bit late - due to bug https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/10035

you might want to set `$q.defer();` to a variable, and manually have `$q.resolve()` fired when the validation passes - otherwise it still destroys a value within your scope.