# AngularJS - How to set validity true after change the field

Tags: angularjs, forms, validation, server-side

I've followed [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37487097/6009677) to run custom server side validation for unique email constraint.

This is my submit function on controller:

```
function submit(form){
  CompanyUser.save(vm.model)
      .success(function(data) {
          vm.closeModal();
          toastSucess(data);
      })
      .error(function(data) {
          if(data.code == 'error_duplicated_email')
              form['email'].$setValidity("uniqueEmail", false);
      });
```

}

and here my email piece of HTML code:

```
<form name="form" novalidate ng-click="form.$valid && vm.submit(form)">
    <div class="form-group" ng-class="{ 'has-error': form.$submitted && form.email.$error.uniqueEmail }">
        <label>E-mail</label>
        <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" ng-model="vm.model.email" required>
        <span ng-show="form.$submitted && form.email.$error.uniqueEmail" class="help-block">Duplicated e-mail</span>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-white" ng-click="vm.closeModal()">Cancel</button>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

And works fine once that server returns the error. But, then I change the email and try to submit, but I cannot do it anymore. I think that is because I've set the `validity` to `false`. So how can I set to true to try to submit the form again?

Comment: Can you also include the code for the submit button?

Comment: I had just added the form code & the submit button code.

Comment: You probably need to add a `ng-change="form.$valid=true"` to your `<input type="email"..`

Comment: That's works fine dude! Good job.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution from @code90:

I needed to add a `ng-change="form.$valid=true"` to the `<input type="email"..`

and it works fine!

Comment: I need to set the validity of that specific control

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use the `$setPristine();` method.

From angular [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/form.FormController):

> **$setPristine();** Sets the form to its pristine state.
>
> This method sets the form's $pristine state to true, the $dirty state
>   to false, removes the ng-dirty class and adds the ng-pristine class.
>   Additionally, it sets the $submitted state to false.
>
> This method will also propagate to all the controls contained in this
>   form.
>
> Setting a form back to a pristine state is often useful when we want
>   to 'reuse' a form after saving or resetting it.

Comment: But where would you use it?

Comment: once that server returns the error, do you reset your fields?