# angularjs to check if email already exists

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to implement the answer provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28717378/angularjs-custom-directive-to-check-if-a-username-exists) to throw in an error if the email is already in the data base. here is my current directive, it throws an error that User is not defined. I have already a `User.js` file which defines the user and it is imported into the the `api.js` file. I don't know how to access my backend `User.js` file which links to the database.

```
'use strict';

myApp.directive('emailExists', function($timeout, User) {
  return {
    restrict: 'AE',
    require: 'ngModel',
    link: function(scope, elm, attr, model) {
      model.$asyncValidators.usernameExists = function(email) {
        var searchUser = {
          email: email
        };
        User.findOne(searchUser, function (user) {
          if(user)     
          then(function(res){+
          $timeout(function(){
        model.$setValidity('usernameExists', !!res.data);
      }, 1000);
    });
            });

      };
    }
  }
});
```

### update

updated the code according to an answer provided, i had forgot to include the User, however, i still get an error:
[image]

the `User.js` is a model that is included in my `localStrategy.js` which is a service imported to my `api.js`, the file which I run as `nodemon api.js` alongside my grunt serve to startup my app.

here is my User.js file:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var bcrypt = require('bcrypt-nodejs');

var UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  email: String,
  password: String,
  displayName: String,
  active: Boolean
});

UserSchema.methods.toJSON = function () {
  var user = this.toObject();
  delete user.password;
  return user;
};

UserSchema.methods.comparePasswords = function (password, callback) {
  bcrypt.compare(password, this.password, callback);
}

UserSchema.pre('save', function (next) {
  var user = this;

  if (!user.isModified('password')) return next();

  bcrypt.genSalt(10, function (err, salt) {
    if (err) return next(err);

    bcrypt.hash(user.password, salt, null, function (err, hash) {
      if (err) return next(err);

      user.password = hash;
      next();
    })
  })
})

module.exports = mongoose.model('User', UserSchema);
```

Comment: just to make sure, your user.js is placed in your html above the directive file, right?

Comment: That means `User` is not defined in a manner that Angular understands. Is `User` a service? We would have to see how you have defined it and registered it as a module to provide assistance.

Answer (score 1):

You have to inject it into your directive just as you injected `$timeout`:

```
myApp.directive('emailExists', function($timeout, User) {
    ...
});
```

Comment: thanks! i updated my question, that was true, i had forgotten to include it, i still get an error.