# model.$setValidity don't work for $asyncValidators

Tags: angularjs, forms, validation

I'm using the same code as in this question [angularjs: custom directive to check if a username exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28717378/angularjs-custom-directive-to-check-if-a-username-exists)

I have code like this:

```
export default function(rpc) {
    return {
        restrict: 'AE',
        require: 'ngModel',
        link: function(scope, elm, attr, model) {
            rpc.then((service) => {
                model.$asyncValidators.usernameExists = function() {
                    return service.username_taken(model.$viewValue).then((taken) => {
                        console.log(!taken);
                        model.$setValidity('usernameExists', !taken);
                    });
                };
            });
        }
    };
};


import angular from 'angular';
import usernameExists from './usernameExists';

var module = angular.module('directives', [])
    .directive('usernameExists', usernameExists);

export default module;
```

template:

```
<form name="register">
    <div>
        <label for="username">username:</label>
        <input type="text" id="username" name="username" placeholder="username"
               ng-model="ctrl.username" ng-model-options="{ debounce: 1000 }"
               username-exists />
        <div ng-if="register.username.$error.usernameExists">username already exists</div>
    </div>
</form>
```

and when I type username that exists I've get http request and I've get false in console but the input is valid and I don't get error message. If I type username that don't exists I've got true from console and the same the input is valid. What is going on? The code is the same as in the answer to the question I linked.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that $timeout is required even if it's 0:

```
function usernameExists(rpc, $timeout) {
    return {
        restrict: 'AE',
        require: 'ngModel',
        link: function(scope, elm, attr, model) {
            rpc.then((service) => {
                model.$asyncValidators.usernameExists = function() {
                    return service.username_taken(model.$viewValue).then((taken) => {
                        console.log(!taken);
                        $timeout(() => {
                            model.$setValidity('usernameExists', !taken);
                        }, 0);
                    });
                };
            });
        }
    };
}
```

the other option is to use `model.$validators.usernameExists` if you're returning a promise:

```
function usernameExists(rpc, $timeout) {
    return {
        restrict: 'AE',
        require: 'ngModel',
        link: function(scope, elm, attr, model) {
            rpc.then((service) => {
                model.$validators.usernameExists = function() {
                    return service.username_taken(model.$viewValue).then((taken) => {
                        model.$setValidity('usernameExists', !taken);
                    });
                };
            });
        }
    };
}
```