# Retrieved data in AngularsJS and Directive for checking if a username exists

Tags: angularjs, templates, angularjs-directive

I follow a solution for checking if a username is already present in the DB: defined in this topic "[angularjs: custom directive to check if a username exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28717378/angularjs-custom-directive-to-check-if-a-username-exists)"

In my case, I would like to put in practice that when the user wants to update his data; The script has to be launched when the user wants to change his LASTNAME.

At the beginning, the script should not display the error message

Here **my controller**:

```
// MY DIRECTIVE FOR CHECKING IF THE USERNAME IS ALREADY USED
app.directive('usernameAvailable', function($timeout, $q, $http, ContactService) {
  return {
    restrict: 'AE',
    require: 'ngModel',
    link: function(scope, elm, attr, model) { 
        model.interation=0;
        model.$asyncValidators.usernameExists = function() {   
        name= elm.val();
        return ContactService.searchContactByName(name).success(function(contact){
          $timeout(function(){
            if(contact.length >0){
                model.$setValidity('usernameExists', contact); 
                //model.$setValidity('unique', false); // For validation criteria in the form
                scope.alreadyExist='true';
                scope.contacts = contact;           
            }else{
                model.$setValidity('usernameExists', contact); 
                //model.$setValidity('unique', true); // For validation criteria in the form
                scope.alreadyExist='false';             
                scope.contacts = null;          
            }

          }, 600);
        }); 

      };
    }
  } 
});


app.controller('ctrlEditContacts', function ($scope, $routeParams, ContactService){

    // LOAD DATA ABOUT THE USER
    ContactService.loadPersonById($routeParams.contactId).success(function(contact){
        $scope.contact.ID = contact[0].ID;  
        $scope.contact.LASTNAME = contact[0].LASTNAME;  
        $scope.contact.FIRSTNAME = contact[0].FIRSTNAME;            
    });

});
```

Here **my template**:

```
  <div class="panel-body">
    <form name="ContactForm" class="form-horizontal" role="form" novalidate ng-submit="submitForm(contact)">

      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="username" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Last Name *</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
            <input type="text" class="form-control"
            name="username" maxlength="100" placeholder="Enter Last Name"
            required
            ng-model="contact.LASTNAME"
            username-available
            ng-model-options="{ updateOn: 'blur' }">
            <div ng-if="ContactForm.$pending.usernameExists">checking....</div>

            <div ng-show="alreadyExist=='true'" class="alert alert-info" role="alert" style="margin-top:10px;">
              <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-alert" aria-hidden="true"></span>
              <span class="sr-only">Error:</span>
              Last Name already exists
             </div>

        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="txtFirstName" class="col-sm-2 control-label">First Name</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" name="txtFirstName" maxlength="100" placeholder="Enter First Name" ng-model="contact.FIRSTNAME">
        </div>
      </div>
```

Currently, the script is working.
When the page is loaded data about the user are correctly retrieved and displayed. But the script is equally loaded and the message "*Last Name already exists*" appears. 
So I would like to avoid that and displays this message only when the value of the Last Name is updated (and already used).

Could you tell me how to update the script (of the directive I suppose) for doing that?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: use can use with this condition <div ng-show="ContactForm.username.$dirty &&  alreadyExist=='true' ">

Comment: Thanks it's working