# AngularJS Directive for checking if email already used

Tags: angularjs, email, coldfusion, directive

I follow a solution for checking if a username is already present in the DB: defined in this topic [angularjs: custom directive to check if a username exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28717378/angularjs-custom-directive-to-check-if-a-username-exists)

I put that in practice for checking if an email already exists in the DB. In my application a user can register until 5 emails.
When the user enters an email in the field, the query is correctly executed for checking if the email is already used in the database.

Some error messages have been implemented when the email format is not correct.
A message should be equally displayed when the email is already used (so present in the DB) but I have some problems for doing that (with the 5 fields for email addresses)

Here ***my controller***:

```
// MY DIRECTIVE FOR CHECKING IF EMAIL IS ALREADY USED
app.directive('emailAvailable', function($timeout, $q, $http, ContactService) {
    return {
        restrict: 'AE',
        require: 'ngModel',
        link: function(scope, elm, attr, model) { 
            model.$asyncValidators.emailExists = function() {   
                email= elm.val();
                return ContactService.searchContactByEmail(email).success(function(contact){
                    $timeout(function(){
                        if(contact.length >0){
                            model.$setValidity('emailExists', contact);
                            //model.$setValidity('unique', false); // For validation criteria in the form
                            scope.emailAlreadyExist='true';
                            scope.contacts = contact;
                            // THE VALUE IS CORRECTLY DISPLAYED IN THE CONSOLE
                            console.log("exist : " + scope.emailAlreadyExist);
                        }else{
                            model.$setValidity('emailExists', contact); 
                            //model.$setValidity('unique', true); // For validation criteria in the form
                            scope.emailAlreadyExist='false';                
                            scope.contacts = null;
                            // THE VALUE IS CORRECTLY DISPLAYED IN THE CONSOLE
                            console.log("exist : " + scope.emailAlreadyExist);                                  
                        }               
                    }, 600);
                });         
            };
        }
    } 
});


app.controller('ctrlAddContacts', function ($scope, ContactService){
        $scope.title="Add a contact";   
        $scope.edit_oldContact = "false";       

    // ALLOW TO HAVE SEVERAL EMAILS
    $scope.emails = [
    {
    }];
    $scope.log = function() {
      console.log($scope.emails);
    };
    $scope.add = function() {
        var dataObj = {email:''};       
        $scope.emails.push(dataObj);
    }

    .........
});
```

Here ***my Factory***:

```
app.factory('ContactService', function($http){

    var factory={};

    // CALL COLDFUSION FUNCTION     
    factory.searchContactByEmail=function(string){
        if (string){
            chaine='http://myapp/contacts.cfc?method=searchContactByEmail&contactEmail=' + string;      
        }else{
            chaine='';      
        }
        return $http.get(chaine);
    };  

    return factory;

})
```

Here ***my Template***:

```
<! --------------------------- MANAGE MAILS --------------------------->
<div ng-repeat="(key, email) in emails | limitTo : 5">

  <div class="form-group">

    <span ng-switch="$index">
        <label ng-switch-when="0" for="txtEmail" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Main email</label>
        <label ng-switch-default for="txtEmail" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Email  {{$index+1}}</label>
    </span> 

    <div class="col-sm-9" ng-switch="$index">

        <input ng-switch-when="0" type="email" class="form-control"
        name="txtEmail_{{$index}}" maxlength="100" placeholder="Enter main email"
        required
        ng-model="contact.EMAIL"
        email-available
        >
        <input ng-switch-default type="email" class="form-control"
        name="txtEmail_{{$index}}" maxlength="100" placeholder="Enter Email {{$index+1}}"
        required
        ng-model="contact['EMAIL_'+$index]" 
        email-available
        >       
        <!-- THE VALUE emailAlreadyExist IS NOT DISPLAYED IN THE PAGE -->
        <p>txtEmail_{{$index}} : {{emailAlreadyExist}}</p>  


        <! ----------------- Display the message when the email is already used ----------------->          
        <div ng-show="ContactForm['txtEmail_' + $index].$dirty && emailAlreadyExist=='true' " class="alert alert-info" role="alert" style="margin-top:10px;">           
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-alert" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            <span class="sr-only">Error:</span>
            Email is already used
        </div>      

        <div ng-if="ContactForm['txtEmail_' + $index].$pending.emailExists">checking....</div>
        <! ----------------- Display the message when the email is already used ----------------->      

        <div class="error-container" 
        ng-show="ContactForm['txtEmail_' + $index].$dirty && ContactForm['txtEmail_' + $index].$invalid">
            <div ng-show="ContactForm['txtEmail_' + $index].$error.email" class="alert alert-info" role="alert" style="margin-top:10px;">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-alert" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                <span class="sr-only">Error:</span>
                That is not a valid email. Please input a valid email.
            </div>

            <div ng-show="ContactForm['txtEmail_' + $index].$error.required" class="alert alert-info" role="alert" style="margin-top:10px;">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-alert" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                <span class="sr-only">Error:</span>
                Your email is required.
            </div>

            <div ng-show="ContactForm['txtEmail_' + $index].$error.minlength" class="alert alert-info" role="alert" style="margin-top:10px;">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-alert" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                <span class="sr-only">Error:</span>
                Your email is required to be at least 3 characters
            </div>

            <div ng-show="ContactForm['txtEmail_' + $index].$error.maxlength" class="alert alert-info" role="alert" style="margin-top:10px;">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-alert" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                <span class="sr-only">Error:</span>
                Your email cannot be longer than 20 characters
            </div>

        </div>

    </div>

    <div  class="col-sm-1" ng-show="$index == 0">
        <a href="" ng-click="add()" ng-show="emails.length<5" class="inline btn btn-primary icon_email">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus icon2"></span><span class="addButton">Add</span>
        </a>
    </div>  
  </div>

</div>
<! --------------------------- MANAGE MAILS --------------------------->
```

Could you tell me how to update the script (of the directive I suppose) for displaying the message ***Email is already used*** ?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: does your `scope.emailAlreadyExist` evaluates to `true` or `false` in view ?

Comment: I tried to display `scope.emailAlreadyExist` but no value appears.

Comment: I guess `scope.emailAlreadyExist` is not isolated bound to your directive and controller. 
Try to initialize it in controller as `false` and pass it to directive and update directive with isolated scope binding with `scope:{emailAlreadyExist:'='}`

Comment: I Update the code above. I put console.log("exist : " + scope.emailAlreadyExist); in the directive, It's correctly displayed 'true' or 'false' in the console when I fill the field. But in the view, it's not taken in account, do you know why?

Comment: I guess its because of your directive is not having isolated scope; so updating in value in directive doesn't trigger it in controller. Also if you dont have isolates scope and you use this directive in any other place, may give u unexpected results.

Comment: try putting `scope:{emailexist :'='}` in directive and access it in your calidator as `scope.emailexist` and initialize it in controller like `$scope.emailAlreadyExist = false` and then in template like `<input ng-switch-default type="email" class="form-control"
        name="txtEmail_{{$index}}" maxlength="100" placeholder="Enter Email {{$index+1}}"
        required
        ng-model="contact['EMAIL_'+$index]" 
        email-available
        emailexist = "emailAlreadyExist "
        > `

Comment: Thanks for your help. But could you tell me where I have to put excatly `scope:{emailexist :'='}` ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/152015/discussion-between-rahul-naik-and-coeurdange57).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try below directive :

```
// MY DIRECTIVE FOR CHECKING IF EMAIL IS ALREADY USED
app.directive('emailAvailable', function($timeout, $q, $http, ContactService) {
    return {
        restrict: 'AE',
        require: 'ngModel',
        link: function(scope, elm, attr, model) { 
            model.$asyncValidators.emailExists = function() {   
                email= elm.val();
                return ContactService.searchContactByEmail(email).success(function(contact){
                    $timeout(function(){
                        if(contact.length >0){
                            model.$setValidity('emailExists', true);
                            //model.$setValidity('unique', false); // For validation criteria in the form
                            scope.emailAlreadyExist='true';
                            scope.contacts = contact;
                            // THE VALUE IS CORRECTLY DISPLAYED IN THE CONSOLE
                            console.log("exist : " + scope.emailAlreadyExist);
                        }else{
                            model.$setValidity('emailExists', false); 
                            //model.$setValidity('unique', true); // For validation criteria in the form
                            scope.emailAlreadyExist='false';                
                            scope.contacts = null;
                            // THE VALUE IS CORRECTLY DISPLAYED IN THE CONSOLE
                            console.log("exist : " + scope.emailAlreadyExist);                                  
                        }               
                    }, 600);
                });         
            };
        }
    } 
});
```

and in template make following changes :

```
<! ----------------- Display the message when the email is already used ----------------->          
        <div ng-show="ContactForm['txtEmail_' + $index].$dirty && YOUR_FORM_NAME.$error.emailExists" class="alert alert-info" role="alert" style="margin-top:10px;">           
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-alert" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            <span class="sr-only">Error:</span>
            Email is already used
        </div>      

        <div ng-if="ContactForm['txtEmail_' + $index].$pending.emailExists">checking....</div>
        <! ----------------- Display the message when the email is already used ----------------->
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Sorry for the delay.

Comment: hope you have understand the issue.. :D